# How to parse parameter automatically

Tags: python, flask

The URL request format may be

`http://SERVER/search/categories=Macrohistory&name=Cotton,Gasoline`

Then I want to store the params as the following Hash structure.

```
{
"categories" => ["Macrohistory"],
"name" => ["Cotton","Gasoline"]
}
```

here is an similar request.

`http://SERVER/search/tag=Taiwan,China&name=Cotton,Gasoline`

```
{
"tag" => ["Taiwan", "China"],
"name" => ["Cotton","Gasoline"]
}
```

Is there any built-in or recommended package to get my expected result ?

I can write the parser manually,

but I don't want to rebuild the wheel,

if there are some better solutions, Thanks.

## flask method

```
@app.route("/search/<string:parameters>")
@return_json
def search():
```

Comment: I think you could use jschema after you build your dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

In a URL, the `name=value` elements are usually entered as part of a query string, which is added to the end of the URL after a '?'. That would change your URL to

```
http://SERVER/search/?categories=Macrohistory&name=Cotton,Gasoline
```

With this change, the following code will almost give you the output you are looking for:

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> s = "http://SERVER/search/?categories=Macrohistory&name=Cotton,Gasoline"
>>> urlparse.urlparse(s)
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='SERVER', path='/search/', params='', query='categories=Macrohistory&name=Cotton,Gasoline', fragment='')
>>> urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(s).query)
{'name': ['Cotton,Gasoline'], 'categories': ['Macrohistory']}
```

To get "Cotton" and "Gasoline" as two separate list elements for the value "name", they need to be entered separately in the URL:

```
>>> s = "http://SERVER/search/?categories=Macrohistory&name=Cotton&name=Gasoline"
>>> urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(s).query)
{'name': ['Cotton', 'Gasoline'], 'categories': ['Macrohistory']}
```